# activator assembly]でjarファイル化したら、独自定義のmessagesファイルを読み込まなくなった

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

マルチポストについてご指摘を受けました。申し訳ございません。

別所にて同質問させて頂いております。
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play_ja/tVrQFw8Bsm0

---

お世話になります。

play2.3.8 + scala 2.11.6 + sbtを使用しており、

プロジェクトを「activator assembly」でjarファイル化したのですが、

conf/messages.jaに定義されているメッセージを読み込んでくれません。
初期定義を読み込んでいるようです。

jarファイル化するまでは読み込んでいたのですが、、、

Comment: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1766/%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%83%95%E3%83%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AB%E3%81%8A%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%83%81%E3%83%9D%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%81%AE%E6%89%B1%E3%81%84 https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play_ja/tVrQFw8Bsm0/discussion スタックオーバーフローでのマルチポストについては、現状こういうった感じなので、マルチポストなことを明記くらいはしたほうがよいかも？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`play.api.i18n.Lang` を implicit で渡し忘れていることはないでしょうか。
`Messages()` は `play.api.i18n.Lang` を implicit で渡さないとシステムデフォルトの言語で翻訳します。

http://qiita.com/kawachi/items/4a0a2342a57849653f38
の「よくある例」になっていないか確認してみてください。

Comment: 起動パスにて　"-Duser.language=ja" のようにmessagesのlangを指定したら読み込まれるようになりました。参照URLとても参考になりました。
有難うございます。

Answer (score 1):

直接の解決策ではないですが、sbt-assemblyでplay2のアプリをまとめるのは標準の方法ではない(もちろん色々頑張れば原理的に不可能ではないはず)ので、
よくわからないうちは素直にplay2が標準で依存しているsbt-native-packagerを使う、という選択肢もあると思います